# Compare objects name

Tags: java, object, equals

I need to compare two objects and return true if the name is equal or false if not.

```
public class Team {
private String TeamName;

public Team(String name)
{
    TeamName = name;

}

// I was trying this way but I was not able to do it.
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (TeamName.equals(objet.toString())) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `TeamName` by `name` field in `Team` class.
Repeating `Team` is redundant and variable names should start with a lowercase letter.

For the equality, first you have to check the type compatibility and you can then use the `equals()` method by comparing the `name` String fields.
Rather using directly `String#equals(Object o)` method, you can use `Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)` that spares the null check for the `name` field.
At last, **when you override `equals()`, `hashcode()` should also be consequently 
overriden** in order to keep these two methods consistent.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof Team)){
       return false;
    }  

    Team otherTeam = (Team) object;        
    return Objects.equals(name, otherTeam.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I get it, I was kinda lost. Keep coding

Comment: You'll get my upvote if you'll make the name comparison null-safe through `Objects.equals()` and show how OP should handle `hashCode()` :) Also, remember to annotate with `@Override`

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic  A challenge  for an upvote M. the teacher :)  When we start to write a comprehensive answer, might as well go until the end. So, I did it.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to cast the parameter `object` to a type `Team` first in order to compare their names.

Example:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
     if(object instanceof Team) {
         Team team = (Team)object;
         return this.TeamName.equals(team.TeamName);
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, because `object.toString()` does not return the value of the `TeamName` member variable of the other object (if class `Team` doesn't have an overridden `toString()` method).

In your `equals()` method, you should:

1. check that the other object is actually a `Team` object using `instanceof`
2. if it is, then cast it and get the other object's `TeamName` variable, and compare it to the current object's

Like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Team) {        // check if it is a Team
        Team otherTeam = (Team) object;  // cast to Team
        return TeamName.equals(other.TeamName);  // compare and return result
    } else {
        return false;  // the other object is not a Team
    }
}
```